# Send EOT to process in docker container

Tags: linux, docker, process

I have a process running in docker container
How to send **EOT** (for *stdin*) to this process?

Normally in linux environment I would just use `ctrl+d` (for foreground process)

Moreover `man docker run` for `-i` options states:

> "Keep STDIN open even if not attached"

Then I guess there should be an option to close *stdin*

Comment: Do you mean `EOF`?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Thank you,
It is about EOF, but you achieve this by sending the EOT character
I thought about the other stack* forum but I find docker related questions hard to match

Comment: That's a terminal driver issue, it has nothing to do with communication between programs.